# How to use datatable.js correctly?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables.js. There is data present in the table which I am populating using the get method. But it is showing mistakes like shown in this image [image: mistakes]

This is my code:

```
$(document).ready( function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://206.189.139.51:7070/admin/users",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: 'json',
            async: true,
            crossDomain: true,
            headers: {
                "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token
            },
            
            success: function (result){
                for (i=0; i < result.data.length; i++) {
                    var row = document.getElementById("table-body").insertRow(i);
                    var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                    var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                    ....
                    cell1.innerHTML = result.data[i]._id;
                    cell2.innerHTML = result.data[i].role;
                    .....
                }

                $('#dataTable').DataTable();
            }
        })
    });
```

Can anyone tell how solve this issue? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add some delay before the dataTable function executes. I think the $.dataTable function executes before the table has been updated, that is why it shows zero data.

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#dataTable').DataTable();
}, 500);
```

or to implement the DataTable well, use this

```
 $.ajax({
           url: "http://206.189.139.51:7070/admin/users",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
           async: true,
           crossDomain: true,
           headers: {
               "Authorization": 'Bearer ' + token
           },
            
           success: function (result){
              
               $('#dataTable').DataTable({
                 destroy: true,
                 aData: result.data,
                 aoColumns: [
                    // ...... <---- call the rest of columns from the ajax
                    {data: "password"},
                    {data: "_id"},
                    {data: "_role"},
                    {data: "email"},
                    // ...... <---- call the rest of columns from the ajax
                 ]
               });
           }
       })
   });
```

Comment: It's not working.

Comment: try the other way, check my edit.

Comment: @Boidurja check my edit.

Comment: Edit is not working. It is show this error `DataTables warning: table id=dataTable - Cannot reinitialise DataTable. ` in an alert.

Comment: add destroy: true, before aData inside dataTable function.

$('#dataTable').DataTable({
                 destroy: true,
                 aData: result.data,

Comment: Still not working